# How can I change the directory in which I land when accessing a computer via SSH?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

I always enter the computer in this directory:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ICW/var
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

What does `echo ~` print after you have logged in?

I'm pretty sure that is your home directory, as defined in `/etc/passwd` inside your Cygwin environment.

So either:

1. edit `/etc/passwd` and change the entry for your user to the directory you prefer
    (note that it might be overridden when you run `mkpasswd`)
2. edit your shell configuration files to always do a `cd` automatically after logging in
    e.g. add `cd <some other directory>` to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc`

One of those should do the trick.

If not, try this:

- run `env | find "var"` and see which variables are printed
  perhaps `%USERPROFILE%` or `%HOMEPATH%` are set to that directory
  if so, Control Panel or `net user /PROFILEPATH:<new dir>` should help

or this:

- run `grep -R ICW /etc`
  maybe something is hard-coded in `/etc/profile` or a similar startup script